# Azure AD change temporary password using graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adal4j

I am trying to change the password of a newly created user in Azure AD using Graph API. I am able to accomplish this for a user with a permanent password(password already changed once using the Azure UI) by calling the graph api using the access token for the user in the headers as shown below:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant_name>/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6 

Request Body : {"currentPassword": "Password1!","newPassword": "Password2!"}
```

However, I am not able to achieve the same API call for a newly created user who has a Azure-provided temporary password. This is because I am unable to acquire the access token for this user using the ADAL4J API which returns an error "AADSTS50055: Force Change Password." So if I cant acquire the token for the new user how do I change the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you were acquire the access token using the **Resource Owner password credential flow**.

When we create a user using Azure AD Graph REST, we can disable changing the password when users sign-in first time. Here is a example for your reference:

```
POST:https://graph.windows.net/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {access_token}
content-type: application/json


{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "User7",
  "mailNickname": "User7",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "userPrincipalName": "User7@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Then we can use the **Resource Owner password credential flow** to acquire the access token for this user like below(ensure the parameter was URL encoded if you send it directly):

```
POST:https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password=Test1234&client_secret={secret}
```

Then we can update the user's password using the access token above. And this Azure AD Graph REST require grant the permission `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

### Update

The users have to change their password when they login the Azure AD(no mater the app developed by you or using the Azure portal) first time when you set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` to `true`. Here is a figure for your reference:
[image]

### Update2

And in this scenario, there is no need to redirect yourself, Azure AD will handle all of these for us. When the users try to login-in your app first time, after users enter the correct username/password it requires users to change their password. After users changing the password, it will redirect to your app automatically.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I need to encorporate the force password change on first time login into my application. Since there is no way to find out first time login from my custom app I have to rely on Azure AD for it. Thus I need a way to change the temporary password itself. Is it possible to achieve it in an interactive way using the Azure UI?

Comment: Did you want to change the password when users login-in your app first time? If I understood correctly, this is by design when you set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` true. The users will require the change their password as figure(see the update in the post).

Comment: Preferably I want to do this using Graph API from my app itself. If there is no way to do that only then I will think of using the Azure UI.

Comment: If you want to change the password using the Graph API, then you need to set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` to false, then you can follow the steps in the post to update the password. Please feel free to let me know if I misunderstood the scenario.

Comment: Yes I can do that but, I wont be able to identify that it is the first time login for the user and force password change. Is there a way to identify first time login if forceChangePasswordNextLogin is false?
Thus I am working with forceChangePasswordNextLogin=true where Azure AD returns me an error on first time login saying "Change password". Then I want to call the change password api which updates the temporary password with the permanent password.

Comment: In this scenario, there is no need to implement the **password change** feature in you web app. It is recommend to use the build-in feature to enforce users to change their password. This is more secure. Because users can login with their template password with **any other apps** if we set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` to false. And in your app, we are only able to detect whether the users login **YOUR** app first time and this need to implement yourself. For example, you can log the history when users login-in and check this history to detect whether users login first time.

Comment: So you say I redirect my user to the change password page of Azure UI. What is the address to which I need to redirect in that case? And how do I redirect the user back to my web app after password change?

Comment: There is no need to redirect yourself, Azure AD will handle all of these for us. When the users try to login-in your app first time, after users enter the correct username/password it requires users to change their password. After users changing the password, it will redirect to your app automatically.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it working. I redirected my user to the Azure UI for change password and after completion the Azure UI redirects back to my app. @Fei Xue - MSFT If you post your answer I can mark it as correct.